# Detect item from FlatList and its child after click

Tags: list, react-native, reference, click

I'm running in an issue with React-Native. I have a FlatList where each item contains user's picture (30x30), user's name and a checkbox. These elements are wrapped in a TouchableHighlight:

```
handleClick = (item, index) => {
  console.log(item);
  console.log(index);
}

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList    
      data={datas}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderUserItem(item, index)}
    />
  );
}

renderUserItem(item, index) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handleClick(this, index)}>
      <View>
        <Image source={{uri: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/68.jpg'}}/>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <CheckboxComponent/>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

What I'm trying to do is if users click on the large TouchableHighlight (not only the CheckboxComponent), the CheckboxComponent gets "checked" or not. How can I access to CheckboxComponent in the list? Should I use ref? If yes, could you please provide an example working with a list?

Thanks,

Ugo

Answer (score 0):

to keep state of CheckboxComponent you should use **state** not ref

you can do this

in **constructor:**

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
       activeCheckbox: null
   }
}
```

in **renderUserItem:**

```
<CheckboxComponent checked={this.sate.activeCheckbox === index} />
```

(as you know CheckboxComponent must have ***checked*** prop)

in **handleClick:**

```
handleClick = (item, index) => {
   this.setState({ activeCheckbox: index });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the approach and I'm pretty sure it'll work. However, I don't like it to base everything on index.. Is there another way possible?

Comment: currently I don't know another approach. but if you don't like to use index, you should keep some id or key in each data and then compare it with activeCheckbox state.